# jQuery FileUpload syntax error

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-file-upload

While implementing jQuery FileUpload in CodeIgniter everything seems to work, no javascript errors and the files get created in the default folders (chmod'ed 0777), but there are two issues.

**1. I can't override the default options on the PHP handler provided by the package.** Here is the Controller action I'm using to do so, none of the parameters passed are actually applied, if I dump the options within the UploadHandler I get the default options.

```
public function fileupload()
{
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        # load library
        $this->load->library('UploadHandler');

        # upload file
        $upload_handler = new UploadHandler(array(
            'upload_dir' => FCPATH.'upload/realty/'.$this->_user->id.'/',
            'mkdir_mode' => 0777,
            'accept_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',
        ));
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('error/page_not_found');
    }
}
```

**2. The script is throwing a error when a file finishes uploading :**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Here is the response of an example request :

```
{"files":[{"name":"nebula-ngc-281.jpg","size":590295,"type":"image\/jpeg","url":"http:\/\/test.filipematias.info\/mercadoimobiliario\/admin\/files\/nebula-ngc-281.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/test.filipematias.info\/mercadoimobiliario\/admin\/files\/thumbnail\/nebula-ngc-281.jpg","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/test.filipematias.info\/mercadoimobiliario\/admin\/?file=nebula-ngc-281.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}{"files":[{"name":"nebula-ngc-281 (1).jpg","size":0,"type":"image\/jpeg","error":"File upload aborted","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/test.filipematias.info\/mercadoimobiliario\/admin\/?file=nebula-ngc-281%20%281%29.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}
```

Comment: Can't say for the CodeIgniter UploadHandler part but the JSON you get is invalid (2 root objects instead of 1) you can check on [JSON Formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/] for example

Comment: @scollado yes it's true, but there is only one request being made so I don't understand how it's printing out 2 objects in the same request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this document [Creating Libraries](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html) check how we can pass the param in library

so it would be:-

```
 $options= array(
            'upload_dir' => FCPATH.'upload/realty/'.$this->_user->id.'/',
            'mkdir_mode' => 0777,
            'accept_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',
        ));
$this->load->library('UploadHandler',$options);
```

Comment: I feel stupid now, was focused on the wrong package, that did solve all the problems, thank you!